# Change PFUser username, Parse Integration with Facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am writing an IOS Parse supported application where you can log in with facebook. I've gotten parse to create linked accounts with facebook, but the problem is the username of the parse user is this massive long random string. I'd like to make the username their email (which I can get from facebook's API). But I can't seem to set the username property of [PFUser currentUser].
The reason I need their username to be their email is so their friends can be like, "Oh, I think I'll friend djk@s.edu" instead of, "Oh, hey I should friend SKDJSDFLSHDFBSLDKFjbdh".
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution here is to use the `email` field on `[PFUser currentUser]`. It's a default field you can call just like userName and will save you some headaches.

I wouldn't mess with the username - I think Parse uses it as part of the facebook login/auth process.

If the facebook login for Parse doesn't automatically set this field, you can set it manually by pulling the email address from facebook and setting it for the current user:

```
//facebookEmail = string from facebook with email address
[[PFUser currentUser] setObject:facebookEmail forKey:@"email"]; 
[[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
```

You could also use a new field to the `User` object for user name that might be more friendly, such as "friendlyName" or "humanReadableName" that includes the first and last name of the person.